# NTBackup fails with 8003 and 8019 to restore to Recovery Storage Group

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2003, ntbackup

Taking over a Windows Small Business Server 2003 R2 (SBS2003) that has long been backed up using both Symantec Backup Exec and NTBackup. Now I am trying to be smart and test the restore. Of course this has been tested in the 2 years since installation, eh?

Well, restore fails with NTBackup Event IDs 8003 and 8019 being logged.

The situation: I back up System State and the complete `Microsoft Information Store` (in the tree under `Microsoft Exchange Server` -> `<servername>`. This completes just fine and leaves me with a backup file ca. 55GB in size and that is about right considering our Exchange usage.

Now I create a Recovery Storage Group in Exchange System-Manager parallel to `Erste Speichergruppe`. I add an unmounted database for the only mailbox store(?) we have (and that SBS allows).

Back in NTBackup I find the backup medium, and in there `<servername>\Microsoft Information Store\Erste Speichergruppe` (First Storage Group?). Three entries are visible:

- Log Files
- Postfachspeicher (`<servername>`) (Mailbox Store)
- Öffentlicher Informationsspeicher (Public Folders)

I select only the mailbox store and start the recover, thereby selecting an empty directory for temp files and the original `<servername>` as target. I select "Last Restore Set" and press OK. After 5-10s I get a "failed" status. The report reads somthing like this:

> Exchange data could not be restored to `<servername>\Microsoft Information Store\Erste Speichergruppe`.

The Application event log shows entries 8003 (states the failed backup) and 8019 (no more information either) from source NTBackup.

How am I supposed to debug *that*?